# Previewing bibliography entries on mouse-over of the PDF's citation links

Tags: bibtex, pdf, fancytooltips

I had the brilliant idea to have my generated PDF display the bibliography entry as a tooltip when someone hovers over the citation number with his/her mouse pointer.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/override-default-cite-tooltip) which seems to solve the same problem, but can't get the cite command redefinition to work, and for the variants presented in the answer, the tooltip (which seems to default to "Go to page X") is not really modified, rather an annotation is added.

Is it even possible to change this tooltip, or is it something deduced by the PDF viewer?
The only seemingly reliable solution is the [`fancy-preview`](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/) package, which uses [`fancytooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) with a perl script to generate the pdf. I'd like to avoid extra build steps if possible.

Comment: Have you seen this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932 ?

Comment: Here is a question of mine, answered by AleXG, not directly related to your needs, but it could be used, perhaps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-from-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip. And I second darthbith's comment that your title is completely misleading

Comment: @AlexG Doesn't show any result with LaTeX (using qpdfview), and gives an error with PDFLaTeX: `! pdfTeX error (ext4): link annotations cannot be inside an XForm.`

Comment: Well, the question title is a default and the web form didn't even mention I forgot to write something sensible there. Fixed.

Comment: @rubenvb Sorry, AdobeReader is required

Comment: @rubenvb Thanks! I'll delete my previous comment then :-)

Comment: @rubenvb: Ok, I'll can't change my comment, since it's too old, but thanks for editing the title!