# hyperref: how to change contents of tooltips?

Tags: hyperref

If I put mouse over reference in pdf file which made by LaTeX with hyperref style, then appears tooltip with information "Go to page ...." with number of page where this reference is. Is it possible to change info inside of tooltip? It will be very useful to get this reference inside of tooltip. I found here discussion this topic [Override default cite tooltip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126908/override-default-cite-tooltip) with help of pdfcomment and usebib. Unfortunately this solution does not work with multiple references in \cite command and does not work with group citing like star command in reftex4-1 style. In hyperef.sty file I do not find definition of tooltip's content in order to redefine it.

Comment: that's probably done with the `cooltooltips` package.

Comment: @naphaneal It is not so useful. You need to make tooltip for each refertence. Furthermore, it works only with Acrobat and does not work with evince for example.